# Is it possible to use handlDateClick from Fullcalendar.io to populate the start date in the react-datepicker?

Tags: fullcalendar, momentjs, react-datepicker

Just a simple question is it possible to use Fullcalendar.io's "dateClick" to automatically set the start date in react-datepicker.

Currently, I have my dateClick calling my modal which contains the following

```
                    <DatePicker
                    className="form-control"
                    selected={this.state.start}
                    excludeOutOfBoundTimes
                    onChange={this.handleStartChange}
                    showTimeSelect
                    dateFormat="Pp"
                    minDate={new Date()}
                     />
```

The same modal is used for a generic add event button that defaults to the current date, but can their be a "?" that will choose between if there is a selected date or just to use the current date?

Comment: well, dateClick allows you to provide a callback function. Within that function, you can do anything you like. So I don't see why you couldn't use it to set a date in a datepicker at that moment. I don't know react specifically, but in theory it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: However, clicking a date doesn't make that date "selected" in fullCalendar. If you're allowing users to add events via a button, why not allow them to add them by selecting a time directly on the calendar instead? See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-clicking-selecting (specifically the "select" callback (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/select-callback) and the demos). You could allow the user to select a time period (more flexible than clicking a single day) and then show the modal when they've made their selection, with the start and end dates pre-populated.

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks ill try that.